# Apply script for placeholder in contact form 7

Tags: javascript, html, forms, placeholder, contact-form

I am using this HTML code to display contact form:

```
<input type="text" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Name:';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Name:')this.value='';" value="Name:" name="name">
    <input type="text" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Phone:';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Phone:')this.value='';" value="Phone:" name="phone">
        <input type="text" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Email:';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Email:')this.value='';" value="Email:" name="email">
        <textarea onfocus="if(this.value=='Message!')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Message!';">Message!</textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="sub_btn"/>
```

In this form my placeholder working well. Means when mouse focus placeholder disappear but when mouse out placeholder appear again. I want same in contact form 7.

**Question:**

How can I apply this script on contact form 7 fields. `onfocus="if(this.value=='Message!')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Message!';"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for textareas, the *value* attribute doesn't work. You should use something like (didn't test this snippet):

```
onfocus="if(this.textContent=='Message!')this.innerHTML='';"
onblur="if(this.textContent=='')this.innerHTML='Message!';"
```

The *textContent* attribute is analogue to *innerHTML* but it strips the content from HTML tags.

cheers,